# How to input database entries to Cursor

Tags: android, sql, database, nullpointerexception, listactivity

I've got this problem. I've got a ListActivity, in which i want to inport all my Database entries, which I afterwards want to see on my List.

Now there's a Nullpointer exception Problem, when i get all Data from my Table. You see it at Step2.

Here's the Code of the ListActivity:

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats;


import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.ADFilterDBAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;



public class CreatedADFilters extends ListActivity {

    //Variablen deklaration
    private ADFilterDBAdapter mDbHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        //Hier wir die Datenbank aufgerufen
        mDbHelper = new ADFilterDBAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        System.out.println("STEP1"); //Until here it works



        Cursor c = mDbHelper.getAllADFilter();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        System.out.println("STEP2"); //Here's the problem I don't get.


    }

    }
```

So and here's the Code-Part of my DB-Adapter:

```
    public Cursor getAllADFilter() {

        return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID,
                NAME, KEYWORD, CACHE }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, please gimme some advice.

Thank you in advance!

So here's the whole DB-Adapter for this Table:

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class ADFilterDBAdapter {

        public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
        public static final String NAME = "name";
        public static final String KEYWORD = "keyword";
        public static final String CACHE = "cache";

        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "adfilter";

        private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

        private final Context mCtx;

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBAdapter.DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            }
        }

        /**
         * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
         * opened/created
         * 
         * @param ctx
         *            the Context within which to work
         */
        public ADFilterDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
        }

        /**
         * Open the ADFilter database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
         * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
         * signal the failure
         * 
         * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
         *         initialization call)
         * @throws SQLException
         *             if the database could be neither opened or created
         */
        public ADFilterDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
            this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * close return type: void
         */
        public void close() {
            this.mDbHelper.close();
        }

        /**
         * Create a new ADFilter. If the car is successfully created return the new
         * rowId for that ADFilter, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
         * 
         * @param name
         * @param keyword
         * @param cache
         * @return rowId or -1 if failed
         */
        public long createADFilter(String name, String keyword, String cache){
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(NAME, name);
            initialValues.put(KEYWORD, keyword);
            initialValues.put(CACHE, cache);
            return this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        /**
         * Delete the ADFilter with the given rowId
         * 
         * @param rowId
         * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
         */
        public boolean deleteADFilter(long rowId) {

            return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        /**
         * Return a Cursor over the list of all ADFilter in the database
         * 
         * @return Cursor over all ADFilters
         */
        public Cursor getAllADFilter() {

            return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID,
                    NAME, KEYWORD, CACHE }, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        /**
         * Return a Cursor positioned at the ADFilter that matches the given rowId
         * @param rowId
         * @return Cursor positioned to matching ADFilter, if found
         * @throws SQLException if ADFilter could not be found/retrieved
         */
        public Cursor getADFilter(long rowId) throws SQLException {

            Cursor mCursor =

            this.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID, NAME,
                    KEYWORD, CACHE}, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }

        /**
         * Update the ADFilter
         * 
         * @param rowId
         * @param name
         * @param keyword
         * @param cache
         * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
         */
        public boolean updateADFilter(long rowId, String name, String keyword,
                String cache){
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(NAME, name);
            args.put(KEYWORD, keyword);
            args.put(CACHE, cache);

            return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) >0; 
        }

    }
```

And here's the global DB-Adapter:

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "filterit"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_ADFILTER =
       "create table adfilter (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " //$NON-NLS-1$
    + ADFilterDBAdapter.NAME+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
    + ADFilterDBAdapter.KEYWORD+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
    + ADFilterDBAdapter.CACHE+ " TEXT" + ");"; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SFILTER = "create table sfilter (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " //$NON-NLS-1$
    +SFilterDBAdapter.NAME+" TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
    +SFilterDBAdapter.KEYWORD+" TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
    +SFilterDBAdapter.COLOR+" TEXT,"//$NON-NLS-1$  //$NON-NLS-2$
    +SFilterDBAdapter.SMILEY+" TEXT"+ ");";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ADMESSAGES = "create table admessages (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " //$NON-NLS-1$
    +ADMessagesDBAdapter.PHONENUMBER+" TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
    +ADMessagesDBAdapter.MESSAGE+" TEXT,"+ ");"; //$NON-NLS-1$  //$NON-NLS-2$


    private final Context context; 
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param ctx
     */
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ADFILTER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SFILTER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ADMESSAGES);           
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {               
            // Adding any table mods to this guy here
        }
    } 

   /**
     * open the db
     * @return this
     * @throws SQLException
     * return type: DBAdapter
     */
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        this.db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * close the db 
     * return type: void
     */
    public void close() 
    {
        this.DBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

I Hope that helps you out.. =)

Comment: One reason can be that there is no data in database so cursor is null

Comment: how can i test that? how can i fix that, so i dont get a nullpointer exception?

Comment: Are you sure that your database or table was created? Check to make sure that the database and the table exist.

Comment: ill post more code about my Database im sure it it's created, if not =) you found the problem, but how can i fix it.. sorry im still nab at  android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **ingsaurabh** noted, you may have nothing in DB.
Just note, that Cursor should never be null even if result set is empty; just Cursor.getCount() shall return 0.  Be sure to always do Cursor.moveToNext() to advance to **first** record in result set.
We need your *startManagingCursor* method to get you answer.

Comment: thx for your answer, yes it was a DB-Problem Code worked. And also thx for your Tips!